# Getting the count along with one top row description with joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

We need to show the count of child table rows along with the top 1 last row object name in single query, below is the detail:

```
Table 1
CategoryID   Name 
1           Fruits 
2           Foods
3           Drinks

Table 2
ProductID   Name    CategoryID
1           Banana      1
2           Mango       1
3           Pineapple   1
4           Whisky      3
5           Water       3


Result
CategoryID      Name        Items       ItemDisplayText
1               Fruits      3           Pineapple & More 2
```

I have searched on many other questions, and probable there would be one identical, but I couldn't found the one, any help would be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: sqlfiddle/rextester, and best effort to date please

Comment: And how do you choose "Pineapple" for the display text?  And what happened to category 3?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this names comes from the last row of product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the temporary tables:

```
declare @table1 table ( category int,
                    name varchar(10)
                    )

declare @table2 table ( product int,
                    name varchar(10),
                    category int
                    )

insert into @table1 (category, name)
values  (1, 'Fruits'),
        (2, 'Foods'),
        (3, 'Drinks')

insert into @table2 (product, name, category)
values  (1, 'Banana', 1),
        (2, 'Mango', 1),
        (3, 'Pineapple', 1),
        (4, 'Whisky', 3),
        (5, 'Water', 3)
```

And then, the following query:

```
select t1.*, 
count(t2.product) as items, 
(select top 1 name from @table2 where category = t1.category order by product desc) + ' & more ' + convert(varchar(10), count(t2.product) - 1) as 'item display text'
from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2 on t1.category = t2.category
group by t1.category, t1.name
```

The result obtained:

```
category    name       items       item display text
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------------
1           Fruits     3           Pineapple & more 2
3           Drinks     2           Water & more 1

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
For the comment question: you can use the xml result (changing the top constraint and the subtraction if needed):

```
select t1.*, 
count(t2.product) as items, 
stuff((select ', ' + t.n from (select top 2 name as n from @table2 where category = t1.category order by product desc) t for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') + ' & more ' + convert(varchar(10), count(t2.product) - 2) as 'item display text'
from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2 on t1.category = t2.category
group by t1.category, t1.name
```

Comment: Great, its working as expected, I know its too much, but can you suggest me how to get the text like Pineapple, Mango & more 1(Or whatever count - 2), Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The trick appears to be the display text.  I would go for conditional aggregation with `row_number()` to get the product name that you want:

```
select t2.categoryId, t2.name, count(*) as Items,
       (max(case when seqnum = 1 then t2.name end) +
        (case when count(*) >= 2 then ' & More ' + cast(count(*) - 1 as varchar(255))
              else ''
         end)
        ) as ItemDisplayText
from t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by categoryId order by ProductId desc) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t2.categoryId = t1.categoryId
group by t2.categoryId, t2.name;
```

Comment: sorry it looks weird to me to ask again, as already you have answered, is this query is optimized? I mean we are having tons of data be inserted every day.

Comment: Giving wrong result, there is neither display text correctly, nor grouped.

Comment: @BanshiGurjar . . . 'wrong result" doesn't really help.  You should explain what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** we can achieve this by using STUFF with TOP for the first row from the table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(CategoryID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES  
(1,           'Fruits'), 
(2,           'Foods'),
(3,           'Drinks')

CREATE TABLE #Table2(ProductID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), CategoryID INT)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES
(1,           'Banana',      1),
(2,           'Mango',       1),
(3,           'Pineapple',   1),
(4,           'Whisky',      3),
(5,           'Water',       3)
```

--Following code is selecting all the matching values in the format of our requirement

```
SELECT b.CategoryID,
    a.NAME,
    COUNT(b.ProductID) AS Items,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + x.NAME FROM #table2 x
            WHERE x.CategoryID = b.CategoryID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As ItemDisplayText
FROM #Table2 b
INNER JOIN #Table1 a ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
GROUP BY b.CategoryID, a.NAME

Output: CategoryID  NAME    Items   ItemDisplayText
        1           Fruits  3       Banana,Mango,Pineapple
        3           Drinks  2       Whisky,Water
```

--This is selecting only one row as we expect in our output

```
SELECT b.CategoryID,
    a.NAME,
    COUNT(b.ProductID) AS Items,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + x.NAME FROM #table2 x
            WHERE x.CategoryID = b.CategoryID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As ItemDisplayText
FROM #Table2 b
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #Table1 ORDER BY CategoryID) a ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
GROUP BY b.CategoryID, a.NAME

Output: CategoryID  NAME    Items   ItemDisplayText
        1           Fruits  3       Banana,Mango,Pineapple
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

```
SELECT table1.*,count(t2.name) as items ,concat(derived.name, " and More ",count(t2.name)) as ItemDisplayText FROM 
        test.table1 join table2 t2 
            on table1.category = t2.category 
        join (select tab2.product,tab2.name,tab2.category from table2 tab2 where tab2.product = (select max(table2.product)from table2 where tab2.category = table2.category group by table2.category)) derived 
            on derived.category = t2.category
         -- where table1.category = 1 -- uncomment this if you want to filter with category id
    group by table1.category;
```

Output

```
category  name      items  ItemDisplayText
1         Fruits      3    Pineapple and More 3
3          Drinks     2    Water and More 2
```

I tried this in mysql , hope this works in SQL-Server. Ask if any doubt.